# Get sub Map based on a list of keys

Tags: java

What is the fastest way to get new map using subKeySet of an existing Map?

Example:

existing map is:

```
1|"one"

2|"two"

3|"three"
```

KeySet is: `1,2,3`

Than I clone this keyset and remove first value: `2,3`
What is the fastest way to get this map:

```
2|"two"

3|"three"
```

using new keyset

Comment: Wow, my question is duplicating a question asked one year later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava has [Maps.filterKeys()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterKeys) method specifically for this purpose:

```
Maps.filterKeys(map, Predicates.in(keys));
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have it, if you removed the unnecessary key ?

Otherwise, create an entryset loop over, and add the required key/values pairs to your new/other hashmap.

You can also use a sortedmap, or [navigablemap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) which has additonal functionality for filtering a range.

or if using jdk 8 you can uses its uber cool new functioanlity :

```
m.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getKey() > 1) // or whatever you want
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: This requires me to use loops I don't want to do that.